# How to path parameter from MsBuild to TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I need to read xml file for one property and that property should be used in Next teamcity build. 
For now i have configuration

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <ExtensionTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\.build\</ExtensionTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
<Target Name="SetValue">

    <!--  ReadAttribute  -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="ReadElementText" File="my.config" XPath="/configuration/version">
        <Output PropertyName="build.PackageVersion" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile>
    <Message Text="SourceProtocol = $(build.PackageVersion)"/>
</Target>
```

But variable packageversion is still empty in TeamCity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your choice of names for the value- build.PackageVersion  is invalid msbuild doesnt like the period.

You got the your paths and extensions packs mixed up to with `$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks`. should be `$(ExtensionTasksPath)\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks.`

So i tested it locally -

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">


  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile"/>
<Target Name="Build">
    <!--  ReadAttribute  -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="ReadElementText" File=".\my.config" XPath="/configuration/version">
        <Output PropertyName="PackageVersion" TaskParameter="Value"/>
    </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile>
    <Message Text="SourceProtocol = $(PackageVersion)"/>
</Target>

</Project>
```

and this works.

Comment: Okey question is the same how to return value from msbuild ;)